# Duda con el funcionamiento de new en C++

Tags: c++, matrices, manejo-de-memoria, vectores

He estado probando el operador *new* de C++ pero hay un caso en el que los valores de un vector se sobrescriben sin que tengan que hacerlo.

En este caso he creado dos vectores, uno de tamaño 16 (representando una matriz de 4x4) y otro de tamaño 4 y les he asignado la memoria correspondiente.

```
    int m = 4;
    int n = 4;
    
    float *a = new float(m * n);
    float *v = new float(m);
```

Después he añadido valores a ambos.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
            v[i] = i;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < m * n; i++)
    {
            a[i] = i;
    }
```

Y al imprimirlos para comprobar sus valores obtengo lo siguiente:

```
a = 0 1 2 3 
    4 5 6 7   
    8 9 10 11 
    12 13 14 15 

v = 8 9 10 11
```

Como se puede ver, el valor de *v* está mal, ya que debería ser 0, 1, 2, 3.
He probado a cambiar el orden en el que declaro *a* y *v*, y funciona correctamente (obtengo el valor de *v* que corresponde).
También he probado a hacerlo con *malloc* y también funciona correctamente.

Mi pregunta es, ¿por qué en el caso que he explicado se está sobrescribiendo *v*?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu problema. He compilado el código que has puesto y funciona correctamente (imprime los valores de ambos arrays de manera correcta). He probado a cambiar el orden de declaración, de los bucles for... y todo funciona correctamente. Por favor, realiza mejor tu pregunta para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: @Londo a ti te funciona y a Golvin no porque el código incurre en comportamiento indefinido, esto significa que podría funcionar en algunos casos como en otros casos  podría no funcionar e incluso en otros casos podría formatear la ROM de un microondas en el pentágono.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto no hace lo que crees:

```
new float(m * n);
new float(m);
```

No crea una colección de `float` de `m * n` elementos ni una colección de `float` de `m` elementos, crea en cada caso **un solo** `float` cuyo valor será el resultado de evaluar la expresión `m * n` o la expresión `m`. En realidad querías hacer esto:

```
    int m = 4;
    int n = 4;
    
    float *a = new float[m * n];
    float *v = new float[m];
```

Fíjate que usamos corchetes (`[]`) no paréntesis (`()`). Esto sucede porque los paréntesis son los símbolos usados para la llamada a función mientras que los corchetes son los símbolos usados para el indexado; `tipo(valor)` será una llamada al constructor de `tipo` usando `valor` como parámetro de construcción.

Por cierto, para borrar la memoria pedida por `new[]` no tendrás que usar `delete` si no `delete[]`:

```
delete[] a;
delete[] v;
```

> Mi pregunta es, ¿por qué en el caso que he explicado se está sobrescribiendo *v*?

Porque estás escribiendo en memoria que no te pertenece. Tal y como he dicho, sobre `a` estás pidiendo memoria para **UN** `float` pero estás escribiendo ocho en su lugar, de esos siete `float` escritos de más algunos llegan a la memoria que le fue asignada a `m`.

Comment: Una explicación bastante clara, ahora lo he entendido mejor, gracias.